# Is a Budapest "transfer ticket" valid for Bus then Metro then Tram?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, budapest

I've just discovered that the railway line to Budapest airport goes to the terminal that's closed (Terminal 1), and not to the one that everyone currently uses (Terminal 2), and therefore I'll have to get a bus (200E) to the train or metro to get into the city centre.

My hotel have suggested that the quickest way to reach them by public transport from the airport is to take the 200E bus to the last stop, Kőbánya-Kispest, change to the metro, then later change to a tram. From the map I've found on the [BKK website](http://www.bkk.hu/en/maps/), that all looks fine.

That then leads me onto the ticket required. I've had a read of the [WikiVoyage page for Budapest under Tickets & Passes](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Budapest#Tickets_and_passes), and the [BKK tickets page in English](http://www.bkk.hu/en/prices/), but I'm still not sure. I'm fairly sure that the Single ticket (vonaljegy) for HUF 350 is no good. I would've thought that a Transfer ticket (átszállójegy) would cover me, which WikiVoyage describes as *Valid for one journey within the city limits, transfer allowed* (since it's one journey with transfers Bus-Metro and Metro-Tram), but having read the [BKK English page on that ticket](http://www.bkk.hu/en/prices/transfer-ticket-2/) I'm now less sure.

So, to take the 200E bus from the Airport, then the metro, and then a tram, all as a single journey, what is the ticket I should be trying to buy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transfer ticket is basically two single tickets rolled in one, sold cheaper but with the restriction that the second trip must take place within 1½ hours.

If you need to take a bus, then the metro, then a tram, that's a total of three tickets, which you can decompose as one transfer ticket (HUF 530) plus one single ticket (HUF 350, or HUF 300 if bought in a booklet of 10).

That's assuming you can purchase a transfer ticket: apparently they aren't sold everywhere. They should be available from the BKK desk at the airport (there's one in each terminal), but if you arrive after the desk close, you'll have to purchase your ticket at a vending machine which might not have transfer tickets. I remember arriving late in the evening at Budapest airport and buying two single tickets to take the bus+metro into the city, but apparently new ticket vending machines are being rolled out, so this might have changed.

No matter which ticket type you get, remember to validate it before each segment of the trip: the tickets never come out of the vending machine stamped. You'll need to validate one ticket at the airport, then one (or the other half of the transfer if you can get one) at the metro transfer point, and another one to get onto the tram.