# How late do the 200E bus and Metro 3 run from Budapest airport into the city?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, budapest

Assuming I can correctly understand the [right](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38430/is-a-budapest-transfer-ticket-valid-for-bus-then-metro-then-tram) [tickets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38432/how-do-you-use-a-budapest-5-30-travelcard) for using the BKK Budapest public transport system, I'm planning to take the 200E bus from Budapest airport to Kőbánya-Kispest, then the metro onwards from there.

However, a possible wrinkle is that my flight is set to get into Budapest fairly late, and even if everything goes well I suspect I won't have got my bags and cleared immigration + customs until at least 10pm. If there's any delays or problems, I could well see that being 11pm+.

That makes me wonder - how late does the 200E bus run? Does the last bus get you in before the last metro leaves, or could you be stranded at Kőbánya-Kispest for the night? And other than taxis, are there any alternatives for late night departures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hunting around on the [BKK english language website](http://www.bkk.hu/en/main-page/bkk-in-brief/), I've found the answer.

There's a handy [bi-lingual PDF of the bus times and connections from the airport](http://www.bkk.hu/apps/docs/terkep/repter.pdf) available on their site, if you dig down enough

In summary:

- From 3:30am until 11pm, there's a 200E bus every 7-8 minutes, which will connect you with Metro line 3
- Between 11pm and just after midnight, there's a 200E roughly every 15 minutes, but you have to change at Határ út M for a 9xx bus to the city
- From 00:21 until 03:30, there's a 900 night bus roughly every hour

Exact timings vary, so it seems worth [printing the PDF](http://www.bkk.hu/apps/docs/terkep/repter.pdf) if you think you might be very late. The latest PDF should be findable from the [BKK english timetables page](http://www.bkk.hu/en/timetables/)